# MS excel function not returning sufficient results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

There is one baseline % column that I need to calculate.
for eg., if the baseline start date is "16 may" and baseline end date is "20 may" and if my review date is "18 may",
so by 18th, 60% work should be done according to baseline. "18-16/20-16"= 3/5= 60%.

```
f1: review date;
d5: baseline start date;
e5: baseline-end date;
```

> if f1>d5& f1e5,then "100";if f1

this is the latest I could come up with. still no luck.

```
=IF(AND($F$1>E5,$F$1<F5),NETWORKDAYS.INTL(E5,$F$1,16)/NETWOR‌‌​KDAYS.INTL(E5,F5,1‌​6)‌​)*100,(IF($F$1<E‌​5,"0‌​","100")))
```

Comment: How do you figure five days for the denominator?

Comment: i did not. i just calculated the difference of baseline start date and baseline end date using the networkdays.intl function.

Comment: What year are you using then?  I ask because 19 May 2017 is a Friday, and you have `16` for the weekend argument, so the function should give a result of `4`  If you enter only the day and month into a cell, Excel will assume that the year is the current year.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are probably trying to do this:

```
=MAX( MIN(NETWORKDAYS(D5,F1)/NETWORKDAYS(D5,E5), 1), 0)
```

I couldn't figure out exactly what you were trying to say, but here are the assumptions and steps I used that made sense to me.

1. The core of what you are wanting to do is to return the ratio between the elapsed working days and the target working days (which you will then format as a percent). This is calculated by difference between D5 and F1 divided by the difference between D5 and E5. In other terms, (F1-D5)/(E5-D5). The formula to accomplish this is

   =NETWORKDAYS(D5,F1)/NETWORKDAYS(D5,E5)
2. To maintain an upper limit of 100%, you are wanting to return 100% if the above result is greater than 100%. Another way of saying this is, if the review date F1 is on or after the end date E5, then return 100%. This is accomplished by passing the formula in step 1 through the MIN() function and specifying "1" as the second parameter (because 1 = 100%). Now you are returning the lower of either the calculated percentage or 100%. Therefore if your calculated percentage was greater than 100%, the min function returns 100%.

   =MIN(NETWORKDAYS(D5,F1)/NETWORKDAYS(D5,E5), 1)

   3. Conversely, if the review date F1 is before the start date D5, you want to return 0 to avoid returning a negative number and maintain a lower bound of zero. This is accomplished by nesting the formula in step 2 in the MAX() function. Also, put "0" as the second parameter. This way if the result is a negative number, your formula now returns 0 because zero is greater than any negative number. This is how I arrived at the final formula below.

=MAX(MIN(NETWORKDAYS(D5,F1)/NETWORKDAYS(D5,E5), 1), 0)

You will need to adjust your absolute/relative references as necessary.

Comment: While your post might answer the question it's difficult to validate it. Please add more description to help understanding it.